# PCB track width considerations based on starting current draw

Tags: pcb, current, pcb-design, trace

I am making a PCB for which I need advice on widths of power traces. I am powering a 3A pump and a 1A solenoid valve through this PCB. I am drawing widths based on the table below.

3A + 1A = 4A. So should I draw the power traces basis 4A or should I keep a margin for surge current drawn during starting? This machine starts and stops pumps and motors every 7-8 seconds and does this for almost a thousand times a day. My problem is that if I draw for 10A then trace width of 300mils is too big to fit easily on the PCB. If according to theory surge happens only momentarily upon starting, shouldn't 150mils be enough?

[image]

Comment: If you are low on space, have you considered opening the soldermask to get more thickness for free in the solder process?

Comment: @winny so 300mils is unavoidable?

Comment: Opposite, have a look here: https://www.pcbonline.com/blog/solder-mask-opening.html

Comment: You could also get a board with thicker copper (70u or even 105u) to increase its current capabilities. And also, 10°C temperature raise is really low. In most designs a 40°C temperature raise of the traces is no ptoblem at all (even at 40°C ambient you won't go ober 80°C than which is not a problem)... Also copper core PCB can be an option to get heat away. You see, there are a lot of options. And you don't have to decide for only one.

Comment: @kruemi but can that temperature rise even happen if the surge current only happens when the motor starts? How long does that surge last?

Comment: I don’t think there is an issue with temperature rise as 4A is manageable with 1Oz copper, what you do need to be aware of is the inductance of the track. Skinny tracks on the Source leg of your mosfets can cause problems.

Comment: @DribbleNibble The calculated temperature raise is theoretical steady state after a certein amount of time with that current. And I have no clue as to how much time that is (if it's in the second or minute domain). I would not worry about spikes less than 10s long just by gut feeling. I personally would just take the maximum average current consumption over 1 minute as a guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a trace passing a lot of current, the failure mode of concern is overheating. Using DC + peak current in the IPC tables sometimes gives you trace widths that are unacceptable. Instead, do the following:

1. Calculate the RMS current, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square. This will take into account the DC current, the spikes, and the duty cycle of the spikes.
2. Use the current from #1 with the IPC tables.
   [image]
3. Sometimes you can have spikes that are so fast that the trace heats up and melts, before the heat can escape into the PCB or atmosphere. Double check that failure doesn't occur due to the spike and the duration using Onderdonk's equation:

[image]

In this case, a 150 thou wide trace can take 38.9 A for a second before failing.

Let's say your traces are still to wide. You've got a few more options:

- Use thicker copper.
- Split the current into multiple traces instead of one trace.
- Pass current though a plane or a pour.
- Back off on the 10 °C temperature rise requirement. This means your PCB temperature will go up, and you might need to think about heat sinking.
- Pass current using wires instead of though PCB traces.

The last bullet point may seem odd, but consider the following table from MIL-HDBK-508, "Wiring and Wiring Devices for Combat and Tactical Vehicles, Selection and Installation of", Table IV:

[image]

For example, an 20 AWG wire at 30 °C can carry 10 A, and the copper will heat up to 80 °C. You then need to pick a wire insulation that can handle that temperature. The standard has correction factors for other temperatures, multiple wires in a bundle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From first hand experiment, 1oz copper 5mm wide burns at about 25A and takes a few seconds to do so. For coping with inrush, on a 3A motor and 1A solenoid, I would be very surprised if 150 mil, 3.81mm wide copper wasn't ok.

Answer (score 1):

The track with is based off of temperature rise so it's also dependent on ambient temperature and the temperature that you're comfortable with. One thing that could be a problem is the thermal cycling, so you might want to stick with the big trace. Make sure you account for the copper weight. Instead of going wider you can also go to a higher copper weight find a PCB Trace calculator to help calculate the trade-offs between temperature PCB width and PCB Trace height / copperweight.